# Error loading raster brick: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, raster

I found an unexpected problem with a raster brick. I created a raster brick and wrote it to a file, but when I load it again and try to apply a simple function (e.g.: plot or summary), I get the following error:

```
Error in .readCellsRaster(x, uniquecells, layers) : replacement has length zero
```

The code is as follows:

```
rb <- brick(list) # create brick from a list of rasters
masklay <- raster("mask_layer.grd")

rbm <- mask(rb, masklay, inverse=FALSE, maskvalue=NA) # apply a mask

writeRaster(rbm,filename="Brick.grd" ,format="raster", overwrite=FALSE,datatype='INT2U')
```

Loading it in R, though, does not work:

```
rbcheck <- brick("Brick.grd")   
plot(rbcheck[[1]], ext=e)
Error in .readCellsRaster(x, uniquecells, layers) : replacement has length zero
```

I don't understand the meaning of this error or how to solve it, I read it is a bug but I don't know what to do to deal with it. In case it is relevant,most of the cells in the brick are NAs, and the brick itself is huge (4 193 KB)

Any comment or help is welcome,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: This error happened when I worked in a windows computer. I re-triend in a UNIX machine and I did not encounter this problem again! I cant say anything more useful, though ;)